# Remove text from a txt file that is in an array

Tags: linux, bash

So I have these two functions: `cMinOption` and `cMaxOption`.

`cMinOption` puts all words from `pt.stop_words.txt` into `myArray`.

`cMaxOption` shows a list of words from `ficha01.pdf.txt`, including on that same list of words from `pt.stop_words.txt`.

I want to know how can I delete the words from the array I created and delete those words from the list that appears in the function `cMaxOption`.

```sh
cMinOption(){
    declare -a myArray
    mapfile -t myArray < pt.stop_words.txt

    sed -i 's/myArray/""/g' ficha01.pdf.txt
    sed -e 's/[^[:alpha:]]/ /g' ficha01.pdf.txt | tr '\n' " " |  tr -s " " | tr " " '\n'| tr 'A-Z' 'a-z' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | nl | head -n 7


    for ((i=0; i<204; i++)); do
        echo "Element [$i]: ${myArray[$i]}";
    done
}

# Called when -C is passed as argument
cMaxOption(){
    # Check if the file passed in $1 is a PDF file
    if [ $(head -c 4 "$1") = "%PDF" ]; then
        pdftotext $1 $1.txt
        echo "'$1': PDF file";
        file="$1.txt"
    else
        echo "'$1': TXT file";
        file="$1"
    fi

    echo "[INFO] processing '$file'"
    echo "STOP WORDS will be counted"
    echo "COUNT MODE"
    sed -e 's/[^[:alpha:]]/ /g' $file | tr '\n' " " |  tr -s " " | tr " " '\n'| tr 'A-Z' 'a-z' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | nl | head -n 7
    
    mv $file result---$file
    
    echo "RESULTS: 'result---$file' "
    
    ls -l result---$file
    echo -e " $(sort -u result---$file | wc -l) distinct words"
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to do with `sed -i 's/myArray/""/g' ficha01.pdf.txt`? this code snippet is going to remove the literal string `'myArray'` from the file; consider reviewing [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then come back and update the question, in particular, include sample input data, the (wrong?) output generated by your script, and the (correct) desired output

Comment: If you are using GNU sed, I guess you can replace `sed -e 's/[^[:alpha:]]/ /g' $file | tr '\n' " " |  tr -s " " | tr " " '\n'| tr 'A-Z' 'a-z' ` with `sed -e 's/[^[:alpha:]]/ /g' -e 's/.*/\L&/g' -e 's/\s\+/ /g' $file`. That will remove the need to use all those other pipes.